# jQuery Page Navigation - setting an active class on a section within a new page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

My client has requested that I include sectional page navigation, which the code below answers. If the user triggers an internal page link, or uses the sectional navigation (.menu) the state of the sectional navigation changes to class .active and then takes the user to their section of choice. It might not be pretty but it is simple and it works.

The difficulty comes when the user selects a link to a specific section  on another page.

I can't work out how to set the relevant sectional navigation on the new page to class .active.

I'm thinking that during the onload I need to strip out the #newsection from the page href and then run a similar query as that illustrated?

I'm looking for guidance as to the best method of achieving my aims or even to a better approach.

Any takers?

I'm using jQuery and the site is a mixture of html and .aspx pages.

Thanks.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

function scrollitanchors(target) {

    if (target != "") {
        var stop = $(target).offset().top;
        var delay = 900;
        $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: stop }, delay);
        return false;
    }
}

$('.scrollit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    $('.menu li a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });

    $('.menu li a').each(function () {

        if ($(this).attr('href') == target) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    scrollitanchors(target);
}); //eo function
```

}); // e.o doc ready

Comment: So the link is to a section on a different page, but that link needs to retain the active class once the new page is loaded?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for asking - the .active class is of course for the new 'section'. Example view projects on page 1 scrolls down, read more beneath a specific project opens a new page and the user gets scrolled to that section. I want to mark the page navigation as active for that section.

Comment: Here's how you can solve it with less code: https://jsfiddle.net/ono3tr0d/ Edit: Ah, I missed that it was a *new* page. Use the URL to send the active section.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle - its strange it works for your demo but the animation doesn't fire in my page although it goes to the section and the .active class isn't being appended. BUT, it is late here in the UK (midnight) so I'll play around again in the morning but I like the snap down of the code so I'll get it working :) but it will be a few hours before I answer again. Thanks.

Comment: #Tibbelit - thanks again. To get it working I had to add back ,html ... weird.. but it works great. Thank you for the lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a string to the hash of url for the second page.

ie:

```
<a href="/other/page#section>Link Text</a>
```

and on the second page:

```
<a id="section">Link Text</a>
```

Then when you load the new page, check the hash.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Get the hash from the url
   var section = window.location.hash;
   // Check if the element with the id in the hash exists and add the active class
   if ($("#" + hash).length) $("#" + hash).addClass('active');
   // Clean up the url
   window.location.hash = '';
});
```

I'm not 100% clear of what you're asking, but this will allow you to communicate a link ID between pages.

Comment: #Sinan . Thanks. That looks like my answer - I need to strip out the #section from the url and then use that in the function above as the target. Brilliant. I haven't tested it but it look exactly what I need. I will test it in the morning and then return to mark it as the answer. Thanks again. Goodnight from the UK..

Comment: [http://www.rws-demo.uk/plugin_demo/aa-is-vis-1.html] as a final comment - the question I asked was part of a larger idea. The client wanted a fixed page navigation system which told the user where they were scrolling to and active classes updating as they scrolled. I couldn't find a method so I tried to write my own - hopefully you can view it using the link. The nav bar also sits below the header when scrolled to the top. There is an email address on the page somewhere if you want to offer suggestions for improvements.